# How to loop records from a directory and pass into a MQ function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, python-itertools, pika

I  have set xmls in a directory `XML`.

```
123.xml
234.xml
567.xml
```

I want my code to loop into the directory and each xml and pass into the MQ.

Currently I am able to successfully sent 1 XML using current code.

I am not sure how automatically create incremanetal `UUID` for each XML in folder and how loop in the below code.

**Current Working Code for harcorded XML value**

```
import ssl
!pip install pika
import pika
import uuid


def send(message):

    uui = uuid.uuid4()
    mydoc = open('123.xml')
    xml = mydoc.read()    


    ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(ssl._create_unverified_context())
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='xxxxx', password='xxxx')
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='xxxx', port=5671, virtual_host ='abcd' , 
                                        credentials=credentials, ssl_options=ssl_options))

    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='xxxxxx', routing_key='',properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                          headers={'uuid': str(uui)}), body=xml)
    connection.close()

    print(message + ' ' + str(uui))

    return message
```

How can do this in python?

Comment: Looking for the answer, I have similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the list of XMLs in the directory?

Just read the directory and get the files in the directory, then loop through it to perform your action.

```
import ssl
!pip install pika
import pika
import uuid
import os


def send(message):

    xml_files = [file for file in os.listdir(path_to_your_directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path_to_your_directory, file)) and file.split('.')[-1] == 'xml']
    uui = uui = uuid.uuid4()

    for file in xml_file:
        mydoc = open(file)
        xml = mydoc.read()    


        ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(ssl._create_unverified_context())
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='xxxxx', password='xxxx')
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='xxxx', port=5671, virtual_host ='abcd' , 
                                        credentials=credentials, ssl_options=ssl_options))

        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='xxxxxx', routing_key='',properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                          headers={'uuid': str(uui)}), body=xml)
        connection.close()
        next_uui_hex = hex(int(str(uui).replace('-','').upper(),16) + 1)
        uui = uuid.UUID(next_uui_hex[2:11] + '-' + next_uui_hex[11:15] + '-' + next_uui_hex[15:19] + '-' + next_uui_hex[19:23] + '-' + next_uui_hex[23:])

        print(message + ' ' + str(uui))

    return message
```

Comment: Can you write the answer incorporated with code written above. This would be easy understand for future readers.

Comment: @How would `uuid`  get incremented and how would I change this part of the code `mydoc = open('123.xml')`

Comment: @pankaj, have added the code which increments the uuid by 1 for every iteration